# Receiving a 404 when attempting to load a data source with SDS

Tags: bing, bing-api, bing-maps

When attempting to trigger a data load via the directions found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg585130 I run into a 404 response. I've read over it several times and I keep coming back around to the same issue I was wondering if something has changed with the latest deployment or if I am doing something wrong... I have inlcuded the rest call that I am trying to make below... minus my Api Key.

http://spatial.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Dataflows/LoadDataSource?dataSourceName=StoreDetail&loadOperation=complete&dataLocation=http%3a%2f%2finternaldevelopment.blob.core.windows.net%2fstoredata%2fDSFStoreData.xml&input=xml&output=xml&key=

Any help that can be offered would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that I experienced was related to the issue that I had failed to include the following values as part of the request headers during my rest call.

Expect: 100-continue

Connection: Keep-Alive